# How to choose posts from array of categories but not in other array of categories?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress

Here's what I am trying to achieve:

I have a post that is in category A,B,C,D. I want to show posts included in category A, but I don't want to show posts included in category C. So if I run the query I want this post that is in A,B,C,D to not appear, because it's in category C as well. How would I achieve this?

```
  $notInCategories = array(103,106,132,102,10,57,58,28,48);    
    $args = array(
                            'post_type' => 'post',
                            'post_status' => 'publish',
                            'order_by' => 'ID',
                            'tax_query' => array(
                            'relation' => 'AND',
                                    array(
                                            'taxonomy' => 'category',
                                            'field'    => 'id',
                                            'terms'    => array('10','11','12')
                                    ),
                                    array(
                                            'taxonomy' => 'category',
                                            'field'    => 'id',
                                            'terms'    => $notInCategories,
                                            'operator' => 'NOT IN',
                                    ),
                            ),
                            'meta_query' => array( 
                                'relation' => 'AND',
                                        array(
                                         'key' => 'joke_type',                 
                                         'value' => $type,                 
                                         'type' => 'CHAR',                 
                                         'compare' =>  '='
                                     ),
                                         array(
                                             'key' => 'joke_rating',
                                             'value' => 3,
                                             'type' => 'SIGNED',
                                             'compare' => '>='
                                         )
                             ) 
                    );
                    $myquery = new WP_Query( $args );
                    echo '<p>REQUEST:'.$myquery->request.'</p>';
```

Here's what this prints:

```
    REQUEST:SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_njkf_posts.ID FROM wp_njkf_posts 
INNER JOIN wp_njkf_term_relationships ON (wp_njkf_posts.ID = wp_njkf_term_relationships.object_id) 
INNER JOIN wp_njkf_postmeta ON ( wp_njkf_posts.ID = wp_njkf_postmeta.post_id ) 
INNER JOIN wp_njkf_postmeta AS mt1 ON ( wp_njkf_posts.ID = mt1.post_id ) 
WHERE 1=1 AND ( wp_njkf_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id IN (11,12,13) 
AND wp_njkf_posts.ID NOT IN ( SELECT object_id FROM wp_njkf_term_relationships 
WHERE term_taxonomy_id IN (11,30,50,59,60,104,105,108,134) ) ) 
AND wp_njkf_posts.post_type = 'post' 
AND ((wp_njkf_posts.post_status = 'publish')) 
AND ( ( wp_njkf_postmeta.meta_key = 'joke_type' 
AND CAST(wp_njkf_postmeta.meta_value AS CHAR) = 'joke' ) 
AND ( mt1.meta_key = 'joke_rating' AND CAST(mt1.meta_value AS SIGNED) >= '3' ) ) 
GROUP BY wp_njkf_posts.ID 
ORDER BY wp_njkf_posts.post_date
DESC LIMIT 0, 10
```

**LATER EDIT:** I understand now why it prints differently for term_taxonomy_id. It's because  term_taxonomy_id is not the same with category id.   term_taxonomy_id is the connection between the category id (which is term_id from the table term_taxonomy) and the post (which is object_id in term_relationship) -- what I don't understand it's why it doesn't exclude those categories..

Comment: If it was me, I'd provide some sample data, and a desired result - keeping the example as clear and concise as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the codes below in your php file.

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'posts_per_page'=> your_desired_number_of_post,
    'tax_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'category',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => array( 'your_category_here' ),
        ),
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'category',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => array( 'your_category_to_exclude_here' ),
            'operator' => 'NOT IN',
        ),
    ),
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

I hope that helps,

MMK.

Comment: Hi, I tried to use WP_Query previous to trying SQL with wpdb, but for some reason when I output the request the category array I was inputting was different than what the query got. That's why I copied the SQL and I was trying to do this manually.

Comment: Please see my later edit.. Can you explain why the categories I am inputting for the taxonomy query are changing when calling wp_query?

Comment: i added a new answer. I tested it and i think it will do the job.

Answer (score 0):

You can do what you want using `group by` and `having`.  It is a little hard to relate your complicated query to your simple question.  But, assuming the table with the lists of ids is `wp_njkf_term_relationships`, then you want something like:

```
select tr.object_id
from wp_njkf_term_relationships tr
group by tr.object_id
having sum(tr.term_taxonomy_id in (139, 133, 45, 135) ) > 0 and
       sum(tr.term_taxonomy_id in (103, 106, 132, 102, 10, 57, 58, 28, 48) ) = 0;
```

I would suggest that you add in the rest of the logic one table at a time.

Comment: I'm impressed that you know what the OP wants. I have no idea!

Comment: @Strawberry I tried to explain it as good as I could :) If you read the part above the code it explains exactly what I need..

Comment: @Gordon - thank you for your answer but I am not good with SQL queries and I honestly have no idea how to change the code I have to use the method you suggested. I'm trying to use WP_query again and maybe I can figure out why wp query changes the id's I am sending for categories check

Answer (score 0):

What do you think of using sub queries :

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM table WHERE category IN ('A') ) AS posts_category_a WHERE category NOT IN ('C')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'posts_per_page'=> 100,
    'tax_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'category',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => array( 'CAT 1' ),
        ),
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'category',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => array( 'CAT 2','CAT 3', 'CAT 4' ),
            'operator' => 'NOT IN',
        ),
    ),
);
```

I have 4 posts namely: post1, post1.1, post2 and post3

all posts are in category CAT 1, CAT 2 and CAT 3.

post1.1 is in category CAT 1 only .

When i run the code the results contain only one post and that post is post1.1.

I hope this helps you.

Comment: Hi, my problem is I must use id's because it's a piece of a big program which is using category id's.. When I am using this code: `array(
         'taxonomy' => 'category',
         'field'    => 'id',
         'terms'    => array(10,11,12)
       )` the SQL reads [...] IN (11,12,13) [...] Why does it change the id's I input?

Comment: Apparently SQL is reading the ids by adding one to them. Can you post all the SQL Statement and your php code (WP_Query) ?

Comment: Hi, see the edits please. I added the code I am using now and the SQL string that gets printed.

Comment: can you explain your meta query? And what is `$type`  referring to  in  `'key' => 'joke_type', 'value' => $type` ?

Comment: it's a type of joke which is set with a custom field in Wordpress.. basically a string out of these: 'joke', 'meme', 'video', 'cartoon', 'gif'

Comment: I figured out why the SQL shows different values. See my explanation above.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using this for cases when I have to check for them NOT being in those specific categories:

```
$args = array(
                            'orderby' =>'rand',
                        'post_type' => 'post',
                        'post_status' => 'publish',
                        'posts_per_page' => 10,
                        'order_by' => 'ID',
                        'category__not_in' => $notInCategories,
                        'meta_query' => array( 
                                    'relation' => 'AND',
                                    array(
                                     'key' => 'joke_type',                 
                                     'value' => $type,                 
                                     'type' => 'CHAR',                 
                                     'compare' =>  '='
                                 ),
                                     array(
                                         'key' => 'joke_rating',
                                         'value' => 3,
                                         'type' => 'SIGNED',
                                         'compare' => '>='
                                     )
                         ),
                         'fields' => 'ids' 
                );
```

And this for when they need to be in specific categories:

```
$args = array(
                        'orderby' =>'rand',
                        'post_type' => 'post',
                        'post_status' => 'publish',
                        'posts_per_page' => 10,
                        'order_by' => 'ID',
                        'category__in' => $categories,
                        'meta_query' => array( 
                                    'relation' => 'AND',
                                    array(
                                     'key' => 'joke_type',                 
                                     'value' => $type,                 
                                     'type' => 'CHAR',                 
                                     'compare' =>  '='
                                 ),
                                     array(
                                         'key' => 'joke_rating',
                                         'value' => 3,
                                         'type' => 'SIGNED',
                                         'compare' => '>='
                                     )
                         ),
                         'fields' => 'ids' 
                );
```

It's more code but in the end an if did the trick.. I would have liked to understand why my previous attempt didn't work, but I guess that remains in the mysteries of Wordpress.